# Restarting service (declared in init.rc) from a system app in a Java context

Tags: service, android-source

I have a service declared in my `init.rc` on my platform that runs always, and an Android system app (signed with the platform keys) that is persistent (i.e. always runs), which communicate through TCP/IP.

At some point I would like to restarte the service from the app, the app runs under a defined system uid, however it does not have permission to call `start` or `stop` on the console, unfortunately.

I would like the app to restart the service, just like if I had executed the following in the console:

```
stop service
start service
```

Is there an android framework call I can make to restart a specific service?

Comment: Maybe you can call a function, in your service, from your app to make a call to system start and stop routines? Just a thought.

Comment: Problem is that this is error recovery, so I cannot be sure of the state of the service, and I cannot assume it will be responding at all.

Comment: Can you post your init.rc? If you service run in the same uid with your app, you will be able to stop that service. There is no API in android framework, but you can do it through native code.